# Casting to Float 2 dp in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to cast average_salary and total_salary as float 2 decimal places but I keep getting an error. Am I doing this correctly?

Error: Test Failedexpected 2 to be a kind of Float

```
SELECT 
  j.job_title,
  SUM(j.salary)/COUNT(p.id)::float, 2 AS average_salary,
  COUNT(p.id) AS total_people,
  SUM(j.salary):: float, 2 AS total_salary
  FROM job j
    JOIN people p
    ON p.id = j.people_id
  GROUP BY j.job_title
  ORDER BY total_salary DESC
  LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a floating point, but you can't set it to a certain number of decimal places. The floating point types available in PostgreSQL are `real` or `double precision`.

You can either do this:

```
expression::real
```

or, to get 2 decimal places, use `numeric(10,2)`, where `10` is the precision (the total number of digits) and `2` is the scale (the number of decimal places):

```
postgres=# SELECT (15::decimal/7)::decimal(10,2);
 numeric 
---------
    2.14
(1 row)
```

Note that you will have to cast one of the values in the expression as `decimal`, otherwise it will treat both as `int`, and the division will result in an integer, so casting to a `decimal` after that won't be accurate.

For example:

```
postgres=# SELECT (15/7)::decimal(10,2);
 numeric 
---------
    2.00
(1 row)
```

This also applies to the `real` type, where you would have to cast at least one of the values in your expression as `real` to get an accurate result.

See the documentation for more information: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you are missing `round()` around `average_salary` and `total_salary` as you are just having `, 2` without using `round()`. Also if you convert `SUM(j.salary)` to float then it should give you the expected result.

```
SELECT 
  j.job_title,
  round(SUM(j.salary)::float/COUNT(p.id), 2) AS average_salary,
  COUNT(p.id) AS total_people,
  round(SUM(j.salary)::float, 2) AS total_salary
FROM job j
    JOIN people p
    ON p.id = j.people_id
GROUP BY j.job_title
ORDER BY total_salary DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Note: "float" didn't work for me, I had to use "decimal". Postgres 14.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT j.job_title,
  ROUND (AVG(j.salary), 2) ::FLOAT average_salary,
  COUNT(p.id) total_people ,
  ROUND (SUM(j.salary), 2) ::FLOAT total_salary
FROM people p
LEFT OUTER JOIN job j
ON (p.id = j.people_id)
GROUP BY j.job_title
ORDER BY average_salary DESC
```